# linear map as a product of certain linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Why a linear map $T$ can be written as a composition of linear transformations of the following special forms:

1)$T(x_1,\dots,x_k)= (x_{\pi1},\dots,x_{\pi k})$, where $\pi$ is a permutation

2)$T(x_1,\dots,x_k) = (\alpha x_1,x_2, \dots, x_k)$

3)$T(x_1,\dots,x_k) = (x_1+x_2, x_2, \dots,x_k)$

I mean which theorem. may be some spectral theorem, I am not able to recognize which one ?

Comment: I omitted the word "special" from the title since a special linear map might lead one to think you're asking about $SL(\Bbb R)$ or something.

Comment: Are you familiar with the reduced row echelon form?

Comment: Also, it would be the composition of the above maps...

Comment: Any invertible map can be written as the product of such maps